# Typo in the Women's Health Clinic, Richville, MD card?

Tags: x-files-ccg

We dug out my old X-Files CCG cards to play tonight, and in the process of playing, came across the card "Women's Health Clinic, Richville, MD".

**Card Stats:**

```
WOMENʹS HEALTH CLINIC, RICHVILLE, MD
XF97‐0380v2 ‐‐ Rare
Episode: End Game
Site ‐‐ Cost: 2 RP
Keywords: Site, Mono, Result, Subterfuge
Prerequisite: SUBTERFUGE 4+
Question: You may ask one MOTIVE question.
```

Sites have keywords, which other cards can then play against.  This card has the keywords Site, Mono, Result, Subterfuge, but lets you ask a Motive question.  In the base set as well as the first expansion, if a site had Motive as the question, it would have Motive in its set of keywords.

Here is a sample of a site that makes sense (picture is a little blurry):

[image]

However, the "Women's Health Clinic, Richville, MD" card has Result as a keyword, but you can ask a Motive question.  I can either assume 1 of 3 things:

- The keywords should actually be Site, Mono, Motive, Subterfuge (third keyword matches the question asked)
- The question asked should actually be Result (to match the current third keyword)
- This is actually by design; while allowing you to ask a Motive question, it allows players to play Result-specific cards on the site instead.

We played the card as printed (you can ask a Motive question, but Result cards can be played on it), but the card threw us for a loop.  Does anyone have any information if this is actually a typo of sorts, or by design?

(A spoiler of the cards can currently be found [here](http://vincent.dangvu.free.fr/xfiles-spoiler.pdf) in PDF format for those interested)

Comment: That card says, "You may ask one Method question," not "Motive."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is undeniable, and it seems by all accounts to be a mistake.

ALL other cards that allows questions have the question type as a keyword. Seems like this one slipped through their fingers.